# How do I change the color of a png image in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, images, png, image-editing

I have a png image that I'm using with GIMP that is only one color. I would like to change this color to a different color. Is there an easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 12):

If you mean one solid color over a transparent background then it is easy:

- Set the alpha  lock for the layer (checkerboard icon in the "Lock" line at the top of the layers list)

[image]

- Bucket-fill the layer (without any selection) with the required color, the alpha lock will ensure the opacity of pixels isn't changed.

Answer (score 4):

You can adjust hue, saturation and lightness. The image must be in RGB color mode. If it happens to be an indexed color or a greyscale image, you must convert it to RGB (Image > Mode > RGB)

Indexed colors can be changed also by editing the color palette.

If you have a white background, it will not be affected if you define a color range.

It's in Color-menu.

Original:

[image]

Adjustment:

[image]

Comment: ure a lifesaver, I was attempting all ways of this url https://www.guidingtech.com/change-color-png-image-text-in-gimp/ , however, It did not work, but yours, yes! .